# xamarin forms: How can I close the tabbedpage and show the previous page when click a tab?

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a tabbed page in my xamarin forms project having 4 tabs. I am opening the tabbed page from the home page(normal content page) and initially showing 2nd tab.

When I click the first tab I need to exit from the tabbed page and show the homepage (previous page) in UI.

How can I do this? Is there any tabbed page events are available?

Comment: this sounds like a really horrible UX.  When a user clicks a tab, they expect that the tab they clicked will display.  Doing anything else sounds like a bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can used the CurrentPageChanged event on TabbedPage. 
If you are in a navigation page, you can subscribe and navigate back, but if you just want to replace the top-level page, you can do this:

```
        CurrentPageChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (CurrentPage == Children.First())
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage = {your home page instance};
            }
        };
```